# Infer type based on values of dynamic object

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to get keys to autocomplete in my IDE. The keys are based on `URLPatternComponentResult['groups']`:

```
export interface URLPatternComponentResult {
  input: string;
  groups: {
    [key: string]: string | undefined;
  };
}
```

In my code, I can register new web routes like so:

```
route.push({
  pathname: "/about/:name/:age",
  handler: (groups: DynamicGroups) => {
    return new Response(`about ${groups.name}`);
  },
});
```

The problem is that when I type `groups.` it doesn't suggest `name` as an autocomplete option.

Here is my `route` module:

```
type Route = {
  pathname: string;
  handler: CallableFunction;
};

const routes: Route[] = [];

export type DynamicGroups <T> = {
  [key in keyof T]: string;
};

export const push = (route: Route) => {
  routes.push(route);
};

export const response = (req: Request) => {
  for (const route of routes) {
    const pattern = new URLPattern({
      pathname: route.pathname,
    });

    const result = pattern.exec(req.url);

    if (result) {
      const groups: DynamicGroups = result.pathname.groups;

      return route.handler(groups);
    }
  }

  return null;
};
```

In my server code, I call the `response` function:

```
const server = Bun.serve({
  port: 3000,
  async fetch(req) {
    const routeResponse = route.response(req);

    if (routeResponse) {
      return routeResponse;
    }

    return new Response("404", {
      status: 404,
    });
  },
});
```

Based on the `pathname` of a route, I want autocompletion in vscode for each key.

This part of the code doesn't work at all:

```
      const groups: DynamicGroups = result.pathname.groups;

      return route.handler(groups);
```

Is this even possible? Can I create a dynamic type based on the values of another type?

Comment: If I understand you correctly you want to construct a object having the path params as keys. That is totally possible using conditional types and string template types. [This external source](https://dev.to/bytimo/useful-types-extract-route-params-with-typescript-5fhn) explaines how to do that. I hope that is what you are looking for.

Comment: [This playground](//tsplay.dev/w1Lb2W) shows an approach; `Route` needs to be generic in the path string literal type, like `Route<P>`, implying that you can't have a simple `Route[]` that is type safe. that would be a *heterogeneous* array, so either you have a tuple like `[Route<Path1>, Route<Path2>, ⋯]` and you can't `push()` to it, or you do an unsafe `Route<any>[]`, or you have to refactor in some other way (e.g., simulating existental types, see [here](//stackoverflow.com/q/65129070/2887218)). Does this fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Yeah I realized that and gave up on it lol